# Como agregar ítem a un objeto en php

Tags: php, php7, php5

Tengo un objeto anidado el cual se genera mediante una data base en una `function`. la data generada tiene varios `niveles` de `profundidad` (`data_tree`)

Para entrar en cada `children` uso una `function` recursiva.

Lo que quiero es agregar la data del `ítem` `children2` a `children`.

A continuación muestro la `data_tree` en formato `JSON` para tener `IDEA` de como es la estructura. RECORDAR que la data_tree es un `object`

```
{ 
"data_tree": [
                        {
                            "codigo":"PE",
                            "pais":"Perú",
                            "idioma":"Español",
                            "children":[
                                {
                                    "codigo": "DEP1" , 
                                    "departamento":"Tumbes",
                                    "children": [
                                        {
                                            "codigo": "PRO1",
                                            "provincia":"Contralmirante Villar"
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "children2": [
                                        {
                                            "codigo": "PRO2",
                                            "provincia":"Zarumilla "
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "codigo": "DEP2" ,
                                    "departamento":"Piura",
                                    "children": [],
                                    "children2": [
                                        {
                                            "codigo": "PRO4",
                                            "provincia":"Paita"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "codigo": "PRO5",
                                            "provincia":"Sullana"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                    
                                },
                                {
                                    "codigo": "DEP3" ,
                                    "departamento":"Lambayeque"
                                }
                    
                            ],
                            "children2":[
                                {
                                    "codigo": "DEP4" ,
                                    "departamento":"La Libertad"
                                    
                                },
                                {
                                    "codigo": "DEP5" ,
                                    "departamento":"Lima"
                                    
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "pais":"Ecuador",
                            "idioma":"Español",
                            "children":[
                                {
                                    "codigo": "4" ,
                                    "provincia":"Quito"
                                },
                                {
                                    "codigo": "5" ,
                                    "provincia":"Guayaquil"
                                }
                            ],
                            "children2":[]
                        }
                    ]
}
```

la `function` recursiva que uso es: si tiene children sigue iterando.

```
    $traverse = function ($data_tree) use (&$traverse) {
    
                    foreach ($data_tree as &$node) { 
                        if (empty($node->children)) { //si esta vacío el children
                            unset($node->children); //elimino el children para agregarlo con la data de children2
                            $node->children =$node->children2; 
                            unset($node->children2);//elimino children2
                        }else{

                           //en caso que tenga data como le agrego la data de dechildren2 a children?
                            
                        }   

                        $traverse($node->children);
                    }
                };
    
$traverse($data_tree);
    
return $data_tree;
```

Fragmento del resultado deseado

```
.
.
.
 {
   "codigo": "DEP1" , 
   "departamento":"Tumbes",
   "children": [
      {
          "codigo": "PRO1",
           "provincia":"Contralmirante Villar"
      },
      {
         "codigo": "PRO2",
         "provincia":"Zarumilla "
      }
   ]
},
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 1):

Tal vez esta función te sirva:

```
function joinChildren($data){
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        if( !isset($data[$key]['children']) ){ break; }

        if( isset($data[$key]['children2']) ){
            $data[$key]['children'] = array_merge($data[$key]['children'], $data[$key]['children2']);
            unset($data[$key]['children2']);
        }
        $data[$key]['children'] = joinChildren($data[$key]['children']);
    }
    return $data;
}
$data['data_tree'] = joinChildren($data['data_tree']);
```

Ejemplo de funcionamiento https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0250d73d39ded0b624c5b6819cd433e217fe6d53

Comment: En mi caso la data es un objeto, me sale el error que se esperaba: `Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in file`, como lo haría sin cambiar el tipo de dato? hacerlo mediante la `$node->children`  usando  "->". Gracias.

Comment: Intenta cambiar la función para que procese un objeto en lugar de un array

Comment: Mira: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ef73e534ef4d43d4b939f70fee74bb81c090fb86